# Modify a measure tool in qgis2web - openlayers export - add area function

Tags: openlayers

I found this article on this same site [Labeling the length of each side of polygon openlayers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782484/labeling-the-length-of-each-side-of-polygon-openlayers-3)
I also use qgis2web, export openlayers. I would like to use his code to add the "measure area" function without deleting the existing "measure length" function.
Thanks.

**qgis2web.js** (with only area measurement)

```
    var measuring = false;
var measureControl = (function (Control) {
    measureControl = function(opt_options) {

      var options = opt_options || {};

      var button = document.createElement('button');
      button.className += ' fas fa-ruler ';

      var this_ = this;
      var handleMeasure = function(e) {
        if (!measuring) {
            this_.getMap().addInteraction(draw);
            createHelpTooltip();
            createMeasureTooltip();
            measuring = true;
        } else {
            this_.getMap().removeInteraction(draw);
            measuring = false;
            this_.getMap().removeOverlay(helpTooltip);
            this_.getMap().removeOverlay(measureTooltip);
        }
      };

      button.addEventListener('click', handleMeasure, false);
      button.addEventListener('touchstart', handleMeasure, false);

      var element = document.createElement('div');
      element.className = 'measure-control ol-unselectable ol-control';
      element.appendChild(button);

      ol.control.Control.call(this, {
        element: element,
        target: options.target
      });

    };
    if (Control) measureControl.__proto__ = Control;
    measureControl.prototype = Object.create(Control && Control.prototype);
    measureControl.prototype.constructor = measureControl;
    return measureControl;
}(ol.control.Control));
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');
var sketch;

closer.onclick = function() {
    container.style.display = 'none';
    closer.blur();
    return false;
};
var overlayPopup = new ol.Overlay({
    element: container
});

var expandedAttribution = new ol.control.Attribution({
    collapsible: false
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults({attribution:false}).extend([
        expandedAttribution,new ol.control.ScaleLine({}),new measureControl()
    ]),
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    renderer: 'canvas',
    overlays: [overlayPopup],
    layers: layersList,
    view: new ol.View({
        extent: [2283125.045170, 4809940.953436, 2383123.537919, 4874627.954073], maxZoom: 28, minZoom: 1, projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'EPSG:3004',
            extent: [-20037508.342789, -20037508.342789, 20037508.342789, 20037508.342789],
            units: 'm'})
    })
});

var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({tipLabel: "Layers"});
map.addControl(layerSwitcher);

map.getView().fit([2283125.045170, 4809940.953436, 2383123.537919, 4874627.954073], map.getSize());

var NO_POPUP = 0
var ALL_FIELDS = 1

/**
 * Returns either NO_POPUP, ALL_FIELDS or the name of a single field to use for
 * a given layer
 * @param layerList {Array} List of ol.Layer instances
 * @param layer {ol.Layer} Layer to find field info about
 */
function getPopupFields(layerList, layer) {
    // Determine the index that the layer will have in the popupLayers Array,
    // if the layersList contains more items than popupLayers then we need to
    // adjust the index to take into account the base maps group
    var idx = layersList.indexOf(layer) - (layersList.length - popupLayers.length);
    return popupLayers[idx];
}


var collection = new ol.Collection();
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
    map: map,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: collection,
        useSpatialIndex: false // optional, might improve performance
    }),
    style: [new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#f00',
            width: 1
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
        }),
    })],
    updateWhileAnimating: true, // optional, for instant visual feedback
    updateWhileInteracting: true // optional, for instant visual feedback
});

var doHighlight = false;
var doHover = false;

var highlight;
var autolinker = new Autolinker({truncate: {length: 30, location: 'smart'}});
var onPointerMove = function(evt) {
    if (!doHover && !doHighlight) {
        return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    var popupField;
    var currentFeature;
    var currentLayer;
    var currentFeatureKeys;
    var clusteredFeatures;
    var popupText = '<ul>';
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        // We only care about features from layers in the layersList, ignore
        // any other layers which the map might contain such as the vector
        // layer used by the measure tool
        if (layersList.indexOf(layer) === -1) {
            return;
        }
        var doPopup = false;
        for (k in layer.get('fieldImages')) {
            if (layer.get('fieldImages')[k] != "Hidden") {
                doPopup = true;
            }
        }
        currentFeature = feature;
        currentLayer = layer;
        clusteredFeatures = feature.get("features");
        var clusterFeature;
        if (typeof clusteredFeatures !== "undefined") {
            if (doPopup) {
                for(var n=0; n<clusteredFeatures.length; n++) {
                    clusterFeature = clusteredFeatures[n];
                    currentFeatureKeys = clusterFeature.getKeys();
                    popupText += '<li><table>'
                    for (var i=0; i<currentFeatureKeys.length; i++) {
                        if (currentFeatureKeys[i] != 'geometry') {
                            popupField = '';
                            if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "inline label") {
                            popupField += '<th>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</th><td>';
                            } else {
                                popupField += '<td colspan="2">';
                            }
                            if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "header label") {
                                popupField += '<strong>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</strong><br />';
                            }
                            if (layer.get('fieldImages')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] != "ExternalResource") {
                                popupField += (clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? autolinker.link(clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).toLocaleString()) + '</td>' : '');
                            } else {
                                popupField += (clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? '<img src="images/' + clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).replace(/[\\\/:]/g, '_').trim()  + '" /></td>' : '');
                            }
                            popupText += '<tr>' + popupField + '</tr>';
                        }
                    } 
                    popupText += '</table></li>';    
                }
            }
        } else {
            currentFeatureKeys = currentFeature.getKeys();
            if (doPopup) {
                popupText += '<li><table>';
                for (var i=0; i<currentFeatureKeys.length; i++) {
                    if (currentFeatureKeys[i] != 'geometry') {
                        popupField = '';
                        if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "inline label") {
                            popupField += '<th>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</th><td>';
                        } else {
                            popupField += '<td colspan="2">';
                        }
                        if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "header label") {
                            popupField += '<strong>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</strong><br />';
                        }
                        if (layer.get('fieldImages')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] != "ExternalResource") {
                            popupField += (currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? autolinker.link(currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).toLocaleString()) + '</td>' : '');
                        } else {
                            popupField += (currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? '<img src="images/' + currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).replace(/[\\\/:]/g, '_').trim()  + '" /></td>' : '');
                        }
                        popupText += '<tr>' + popupField + '</tr>';
                    }
                }
                popupText += '</table></li>';
            }
        }
    });
    if (popupText == '<ul>') {
        popupText = '';
    } else {
        popupText += '</ul>';
    }

    if (doHighlight) {
        if (currentFeature !== highlight) {
            if (highlight) {
                featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
            }
            if (currentFeature) {
                var styleDefinition = currentLayer.getStyle().toString();

                if (currentFeature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Point') {
                    var radius = styleDefinition.split('radius')[1].split(' ')[1];

                    highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Circle({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: "#ffff00"
                            }),
                            radius: radius
                        })
                    })
                } else if (currentFeature.getGeometry().getType() == 'LineString') {

                    var featureWidth = styleDefinition.split('width')[1].split(' ')[1].replace('})','');

                    highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: '#ffff00',
                            lineDash: null,
                            width: featureWidth
                        })
                    });

                } else {
                    highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#ffff00'
                        })
                    })
                }
                featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(currentFeature);
                featureOverlay.setStyle(highlightStyle);
            }
            highlight = currentFeature;
        }
    }

    if (doHover) {
        if (popupText) {
            overlayPopup.setPosition(coord);
            content.innerHTML = popupText;
            container.style.display = 'block';        
        } else {
            container.style.display = 'none';
            closer.blur();
        }
    }
};

var onSingleClick = function(evt) {
    if (doHover) {
        return;
    }
    if (sketch) {
        return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    var popupField;
    var currentFeature;
    var currentFeatureKeys;
    var clusteredFeatures;
    var popupText = '<ul>';
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature instanceof ol.Feature && (layer.get("interactive") || layer.get("interactive") == undefined)) {
            var doPopup = false;
            for (k in layer.get('fieldImages')) {
                if (layer.get('fieldImages')[k] != "Hidden") {
                    doPopup = true;
                }
            }
            currentFeature = feature;
            clusteredFeatures = feature.get("features");
            var clusterFeature;
            if (typeof clusteredFeatures !== "undefined") {
                if (doPopup) {
                    for(var n=0; n<clusteredFeatures.length; n++) {
                        clusterFeature = clusteredFeatures[n];
                        currentFeatureKeys = clusterFeature.getKeys();
                        popupText += '<li><table>'
                        for (var i=0; i<currentFeatureKeys.length; i++) {
                            if (currentFeatureKeys[i] != 'geometry') {
                                popupField = '';
                                if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "inline label") {
                                popupField += '<th>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</th><td>';
                                } else {
                                    popupField += '<td colspan="2">';
                                }
                                if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "header label") {
                                    popupField += '<strong>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</strong><br />';
                                }
                                if (layer.get('fieldImages')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] != "ExternalResource") {
                                    popupField += (clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? autolinker.link(clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).toLocaleString()) + '</td>' : '');
                                } else {
                                    popupField += (clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? '<img src="images/' + clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).replace(/[\\\/:]/g, '_').trim()  + '" /></td>' : '');
                                }
                                popupText += '<tr>' + popupField + '</tr>';
                            }
                        } 
                        popupText += '</table></li>';    
                    }
                }
            } else {
                currentFeatureKeys = currentFeature.getKeys();
                if (doPopup) {
                    popupText += '<li><table>';
                    for (var i=0; i<currentFeatureKeys.length; i++) {
                        if (currentFeatureKeys[i] != 'geometry') {
                            popupField = '';
                            if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "inline label") {
                                popupField += '<th>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</th><td>';
                            } else {
                                popupField += '<td colspan="2">';
                            }
                            if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "header label") {
                                popupField += '<strong>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</strong><br />';
                            }
                            if (layer.get('fieldImages')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] != "ExternalResource") {
                                popupField += (currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? autolinker.link(currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).toLocaleString()) + '</td>' : '');
                            } else {
                                popupField += (currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? '<img src="images/' + currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).replace(/[\\\/:]/g, '_').trim()  + '" /></td>' : '');
                            }
                            popupText += '<tr>' + popupField + '</tr>';
                        }
                    }
                    popupText += '</table>';
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (popupText == '<ul>') {
        popupText = '';
    } else {
        popupText += '</ul>';
    }
    
    var viewProjection = map.getView().getProjection();
    var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    for (i = 0; i < wms_layers.length; i++) {
        if (wms_layers[i][1]) {
            var url = wms_layers[i][0].getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
                evt.coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
                {
                    'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html',
                });
            if (url) {
                popupText = popupText + '<iframe style="width:100%;height:110px;border:0px;" id="iframe" seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
            }
        }
    }

    if (popupText) {
        overlayPopup.setPosition(coord);
        content.innerHTML = popupText;
        container.style.display = 'block';        
    } else {
        container.style.display = 'none';
        closer.blur();
    }
};


    map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
            return;
        }
        if (measuring) {
            /** @type {string} */
            var helpMsg = 'Click to start drawing';
            if (sketch) {
                var geom = (sketch.getGeometry());
                if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
                    helpMsg = continuePolygonMsg;
                } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
                    helpMsg = continueLineMsg;
                }
            }
            helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
            helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
        }
    });
    

map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    onPointerMove(evt);
});
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    onSingleClick(evt);
});

/**
 * Currently drawn feature.
 * @type {ol.Feature}
 */

/**
 * The help tooltip element.
 * @type {Element}
 */
var helpTooltipElement;


/**
 * Overlay to show the help messages.
 * @type {ol.Overlay}
 */
var helpTooltip;


/**
 * The measure tooltip element.
 * @type {Element}
 */
var measureTooltipElement;


/**
 * Overlay to show the measurement.
 * @type {ol.Overlay}
 */
var measureTooltip;


/**
* Message to show when the user is drawing a polygon.
* @type {string}
*/
var continuePolygonMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the polygon';




var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var measureLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 3
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
            })
        })
    })
});

map.addLayer(measureLayer);

var draw; // global so we can remove it later
function addInteraction() {
  var type = 'Polygon';
  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (type),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        lineDash: [10, 10],
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        })
      })
    })
  });

  var listener;
  draw.on('drawstart',
      function(evt) {
        // set sketch
        sketch = evt.feature;

        /** @type {ol.Coordinate|undefined} */
        var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

        listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
          var geom = evt.target;
          var output;
            output = formatArea(geom);
                  tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
          measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
          measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
        });
      }, this);

  draw.on('drawend',
      function(evt) {
        measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
        measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
        // unset sketch
        sketch = null;
        // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
        measureTooltipElement = null;
        createMeasureTooltip();
        ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
      }, this);
}


/**
 * Creates a new help tooltip
 */
function createHelpTooltip() {
  if (helpTooltipElement) {
    helpTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(helpTooltipElement);
  }
  helpTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  helpTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip hidden';
  helpTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: helpTooltipElement,
    offset: [15, 0],
    positioning: 'center-left'
  });
  map.addOverlay(helpTooltip);
}


/**
 * Creates a new measure tooltip
 */
function createMeasureTooltip() {
  if (measureTooltipElement) {
    measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
  }
  measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElement,
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
  });
  map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
}

/**
 * Format area output.
 * @param {ol.geom.Polygon} polygon The polygon.
 * @return {string} Formatted area.
 */
      var formatArea = function(polygon) {
        var area = polygon.getArea();       
        var output;
        if (area > 10000) {
          output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
              ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
        } else {
          output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
              ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
        }
        return output;
      };
      
addInteraction();


var geocoder = new Geocoder('nominatim', {
  provider: 'osm',
  lang: 'en-US',
  placeholder: 'Search for ...',
  limit: 5,
  keepOpen: true
});
map.addControl(geocoder);

document.getElementsByClassName('gcd-gl-btn')[0].className += ' fa fa-search';

var attributionComplete ......ecc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Mike for your answer however I was unable to implement the code you provided with the qgis2web code. However, I managed to reach the goal despite having had so much difficulty given my little experience with programming (it took me 3 months). This is the result:

1. clicking on the button opens a form with a request for geometry, length or area
   [image: form length and area]
2. the drawing is a broken line with the measurement of the segments in addition to the measurement of the total
   [image: measure length]
3. with the double click the geometry is closed, the balloon of the total is yellow and further measurements can be carried out
   [image: other measurements]
4. the area presents the balloon with the total in the center, maintaining the measurement of the segments
   [image: area measure]
5. when you change the type of geometry from length to area the measurements on the screen are reset. To completely deactivate the measurement, click again on the measurement button and all the elements on the screen will be deleted.

I describe the modified code of qgis2web:
**index.html**

```html
<style>
...etc... 

.ol-touch .measure-control {
  top: 80px;
}   
#form_measure {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  border: 3px solid #f8f8f8 !important;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: 2.7em;
  margin: 0;
  width: 147px;
  height: 19px;
      }
</style>

<body>
        <div id="map">
            <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
                <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
                <div id="popup-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form id="form_measure" style="display: none">
            <label>&nbsp;Misura:&nbsp;</label>
                <select id="type">
                    <option value="length">Lunghezza</option>   
                    <option value="area">Area</option>
                </select>
        </form>
...etc...
</body>
```

**qgis2web.js**

```js
...etc...

var handleMeasure = function(e) {
        if (!measuring) {
            typeSelectForm.style.display = '';
            this_.getMap().addInteraction(draw);
            createHelpTooltip();
            createMeasureTooltip();
            measuring = true;
        } else {
            typeSelectForm.style.display = 'none';
            this_.getMap().removeInteraction(draw);
            measuring = false;
            this_.getMap().removeOverlay(helpTooltip);
            this_.getMap().removeOverlay(measureTooltip);

            var staticTooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-static');
        while(staticTooltip.length > 0){
            staticTooltip[0].parentNode.removeChild(staticTooltip[0]);
        }
        measureLayer.getSource().clear();
        sketch = null;
        }
      };

...etc...

/**
 * Message to show when the user is drawing a polygon.
 * @type {string}
 */
var continuePolygonMsg = '1click continua, 2click chiudi';

    var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
    var typeSelectForm = document.getElementById('form_measure');

    /**
     * Let user change the geometry type.
     * @param {Event} e Change event.
     */
    typeSelect.onchange = function(e) {
        
      typeSelectForm.style.display = 'none';
     map.removeInteraction(draw);
     measuring = false;
     map.removeOverlay(helpTooltip);
     map.removeOverlay(measureTooltip);
     var staticTooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-static');
        while(staticTooltip.length > 0){
            staticTooltip[0].parentNode.removeChild(staticTooltip[0]);
        }
        measureLayer.getSource().clear();
    
     addInteraction();
  
     typeSelectForm.style.display = '';
     map.addInteraction(draw);
     createHelpTooltip();
     createMeasureTooltip();
     measuring = true;
    };

    var style = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(255, 204, 51)',
    lineDash: [10, 10],
    width: 3
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 5,
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
   color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    })
    })
    });

    var labelStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
    font: '14px Calibri,sans-serif',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
     }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
    width: 3
     })
    })
     });

    var labelStyleCache = [];

          
    var styleFunction = function (feature, type) {
    var styles = [style];
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var type = geometry.getType();
    var lineString;
    if (!type || type === type) {
    if (type === 'Polygon') {
    lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(geometry.getCoordinates()[0]);
    } else if (type === 'LineString') {
    lineString = geometry;
    }
    }
    if (lineString) {
     var count = 0;
     lineString.forEachSegment(function(a, b) {
    var segment = new ol.geom.LineString([a, b]);
    var label = formatLength(segment);
    if (labelStyleCache.length - 1 < count) {
                          labelStyleCache.push(labelStyle.clone());
                        }
                        labelStyleCache[count].setGeometry(segment);
                        labelStyleCache[count].getText().setText(label);
                        styles.push(labelStyleCache[count]);
                        count++;
                      });
                    }
                    return styles;
                    
                  };
                  
var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var measureLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: function(feature) {
          return styleFunction(feature);
        }
});

map.addLayer(measureLayer);

var draw; // global so we can remove it later
function addInteraction() {
    

  var type = (typeSelect.value == 'area' ? 'Polygon' : 'LineString');       
  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (type),
    style: function (feature) {
            return styleFunction(feature, type)
          }
  });

  var listener;
  draw.on('drawstart',
      function(evt) {
        // set sketch
        sketch = evt.feature;

        /** @type {ol.Coordinate|undefined} */
        var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

        listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
          var geom = evt.target;
          var output;
            if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
            output = formatArea(/** @type {ol.geom.Polygon} */ (geom));
            tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
          } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
            output = formatLength( /** @type {ol.geom.LineString} */ (geom));
            tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
          }
          measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
          measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
        });
      }, this);

  draw.on('drawend',
      function(evt) {
        measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
        measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
        // unset sketch
        sketch = null;
        // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
        measureTooltipElement = null;
        createMeasureTooltip();
        ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
      }, this);
}

...etc...

/**
 * Format area output.
 * @param {ol.geom.Polygon} polygon The polygon.
 * @return {string} Formatted area.
 */
      var formatArea = function(polygon) {
        var area = polygon.getArea();       
        var output;
        if (area > 10000) {
          output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
              ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
        } else {
          output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
              ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
        }
        return output;
      };

addInteraction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take at look at this OpenLayers 6 example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure-style.html  It could probably be made to work with OpenLayers 4.  Displacement for regular shapes is not supported on OL4 but you could use the regular shape image as an icon and set an anchor instead:

```
image: new ol.style.Icon({
  src: new ol.style.RegularShape({
    radius: 6,
    points: 3,
    angle: Math.PI,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)'
    })
  }).getImage(1).toDataURL(),
  anchor: [0.5, 1]
})
```

**Update** It will work in OL4 - there is a bug when cloning text styles and the overlay layers used by interactions cannot be accessed but workarounds are possibe:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Measure</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #map {
        position: relative;
      }
      #form {
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 1;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <form id="form">
      <label for="type">Measurement type &nbsp;</label>
      <select id="type">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="LineString">Length (LineString)</option>
        <option value="Polygon">Area (Polygon)</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="segments">Show segment lengths:&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="segments" checked />
      <br>
      <label for="clear">Clear previous measure:&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="clear" checked />
    </form>
    <script>

      const typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
      const showSegments = document.getElementById('segments');
      const clearPrevious = document.getElementById('clear');

      const style = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
          lineDash: [10, 10],
          width: 2,
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 5,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
          }),
        }),
      });

      const labelStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: '14px Calibri,sans-serif',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
          }),
          backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
          }),
          padding: [3, 3, 3, 3],
          textBaseline: 'bottom',
          offsetY: -15,
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          src: new ol.style.RegularShape({
            radius: 8,
            points: 3,
            angle: Math.PI,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
            }),
          }).getImage(1).toDataURL(),
          anchor: [0.5, 1],
        }),
      });

      const tipStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
          }),
          backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
          }),
          padding: [2, 2, 2, 2],
          textAlign: 'left',
          offsetX: 15,
        }),
      });

      const modifyStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 5,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
          }),
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: 'Drag to modify',
          font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
          }),
          backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
          }),
          padding: [2, 2, 2, 2],
          textAlign: 'left',
          offsetX: 15,
        }),
      });

      const segmentStyles = [];

      const formatLength = function (line) {
        const length = ol.Sphere.getLength(line);
        let output;
        if (length > 100) {
          output = Math.round((length / 1000) * 100) / 100 + ' km';
        } else {
          output = Math.round(length * 100) / 100 + ' m';
        }
        return output;
      };

      const formatArea = function (polygon) {
        const area = ol.Sphere.getArea(polygon);
        let output;
        if (area > 10000) {
          output = Math.round((area / 1000000) * 100) / 100 + ' km\xB2';
        } else {
          output = Math.round(area * 100) / 100 + ' m\xB2';
        }
        return output;
      };

      const raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      });

      const source = new ol.source.Vector();

      let modifying = false;

      const modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
        source: source,
        style: function() {
          modifying = true;
          return modifyStyle;
        }
      });

      let tipPoint;

      function styleFunction(feature, segments, drawType, tip) {
        const styles = [style];
        const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
        const type = geometry.getType();
        let point, label, line;
        if (!drawType || drawType === type) {
          if (type === 'Polygon') {
            point = geometry.getInteriorPoint();
            label = formatArea(geometry);
            line = new ol.geom.LineString(geometry.getCoordinates()[0]);
          } else if (type === 'LineString') {
            point = new ol.geom.Point(geometry.getLastCoordinate());
            label = formatLength(geometry);
            line = geometry;
          }
        }
        if (segments && line) {
          let count = 0;
          line.forEachSegment(function (a, b) {
            const segment = new ol.geom.LineString([a, b]);
            const label = formatLength(segment);
            if (segmentStyles.length - 1 < count) {
              segmentStyles.push(
                new ol.style.Style({
                  text: new ol.style.Text({
                    font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                    }),
                    backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
                      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
                    }),
                    padding: [2, 2, 2, 2],
                    textBaseline: 'bottom',
                    offsetY: -12,
                  }),
                  image: new ol.style.Icon({
                    src: new ol.style.RegularShape({
                      radius: 6,
                      points: 3,
                      angle: Math.PI,
                      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
                      }),
                    }).getImage(1).toDataURL(),
                    anchor: [0.5, 1],
                  }),
                })
              );
            }
            const segmentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(segment.getCoordinateAt(0.5));
            segmentStyles[count].setGeometry(segmentPoint);
            segmentStyles[count].getText().setText(label);
            styles.push(segmentStyles[count]);
            count++;
          });
        }
        if (label) {
          labelStyle.setGeometry(point);
          labelStyle.getText().setText(label);
          styles.push(labelStyle);
        }
        if (
          tip &&
          type === 'Point' &&
          !modifying
        ) {
          tipPoint = geometry;
          tipStyle.getText().setText(tip);
          styles.push(tipStyle);
        }
        modifying = false;
        return styles;
      }

      const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: function (feature) {
          return styleFunction(feature, showSegments.checked);
        },
      });

      const map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-11000000, 4600000],
          zoom: 15,
        }),
      });

      map.addInteraction(modify);

      let draw; // global so we can remove it later

      function addInteraction() {
        const drawType = typeSelect.value;
        if (drawType == 'None') {
          modify.setActive(false);
          return;
        }
        const activeTip =
          'Click to continue drawing the ' +
          (drawType === 'Polygon' ? 'polygon' : 'line');
        const idleTip = 'Click to start measuring';
        let tip = idleTip;
        draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
          source: source,
          type: drawType,
          style: function (feature) {
            return styleFunction(feature, showSegments.checked, drawType, tip);
          },
        });
        draw.on('drawstart', function () {
          if (clearPrevious.checked) {
            source.clear();
          }
          modify.setActive(false);
          tip = activeTip;
        });
        draw.on('drawend', function () {
          modifyStyle.setGeometry(tipPoint);
          modify.setActive(true);
          map.once('pointermove', function () {
            modifyStyle.setGeometry();
          });
          tip = idleTip;
        });
        modify.setActive(true);
        map.addInteraction(draw);
      }

      typeSelect.onchange = function () {
        map.removeInteraction(draw);
        addInteraction();
      };

      addInteraction();

      showSegments.onchange = function () {
        vector.changed();
      };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To use as a control you would need to call the `addInteraction` function from the comtrol's click handler function (I replaced the None option with hiding and showing the options form).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Measure</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #map {
        position: relative;
      }
      #form {
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 1;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .measure-control {
        top: 65px;
        left: .5em;
      }
      .ol-touch .measure-control {
        top: 80px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <form id="form" style="display: none">
      <label for="type">Measurement type &nbsp;</label>
      <select id="type">
        <option value="LineString">Length (LineString)</option>
        <option value="Polygon">Area (Polygon)</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="segments">Show segment lengths:&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="segments" checked />
      <br>
      <label for="clear">Clear previous measure:&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="clear" checked />
    </form>
    <script>

      const typeSelectForm = document.getElementById('form');
      const typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
      const showSegments = document.getElementById('segments');
      const clearPrevious = document.getElementById('clear');

      const style = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
          lineDash: [10, 10],
          width: 2,
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 5,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
          }),
        }),
      });

      const labelStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: '14px Calibri,sans-serif',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
          }),
          backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
          }),
          padding: [3, 3, 3, 3],
          textBaseline: 'bottom',
          offsetY: -15,
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          src: new ol.style.RegularShape({
            radius: 8,
            points: 3,
            angle: Math.PI,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
            }),
          }).getImage(1).toDataURL(),
          anchor: [0.5, 1],
        }),
      });

      const tipStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
          }),
          backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
          }),
          padding: [2, 2, 2, 2],
          textAlign: 'left',
          offsetX: 15,
        }),
      });

      const modifyStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 5,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
          }),
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: 'Drag to modify',
          font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
          }),
          backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
          }),
          padding: [2, 2, 2, 2],
          textAlign: 'left',
          offsetX: 15,
        }),
      });

      const segmentStyles = [];

      const formatLength = function (line) {
        const length = ol.Sphere.getLength(line);
        let output;
        if (length > 100) {
          output = Math.round((length / 1000) * 100) / 100 + ' km';
        } else {
          output = Math.round(length * 100) / 100 + ' m';
        }
        return output;
      };

      const formatArea = function (polygon) {
        const area = ol.Sphere.getArea(polygon);
        let output;
        if (area > 10000) {
          output = Math.round((area / 1000000) * 100) / 100 + ' km\xB2';
        } else {
          output = Math.round(area * 100) / 100 + ' m\xB2';
        }
        return output;
      };

      const raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      });

      const source = new ol.source.Vector();

      let modifying = false;

      const modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
        source: source,
        style: function() {
          modifying = true;
          return modifyStyle;
        }
      });

      let tipPoint;

      function styleFunction(feature, segments, drawType, tip) {
        const styles = [style];
        const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
        const type = geometry.getType();
        let point, label, line;
        if (!drawType || drawType === type) {
          if (type === 'Polygon') {
            point = geometry.getInteriorPoint();
            label = formatArea(geometry);
            line = new ol.geom.LineString(geometry.getCoordinates()[0]);
          } else if (type === 'LineString') {
            point = new ol.geom.Point(geometry.getLastCoordinate());
            label = formatLength(geometry);
            line = geometry;
          }
        }
        if (segments && line) {
          let count = 0;
          line.forEachSegment(function (a, b) {
            const segment = new ol.geom.LineString([a, b]);
            const label = formatLength(segment);
            if (segmentStyles.length - 1 < count) {
              segmentStyles.push(
                new ol.style.Style({
                  text: new ol.style.Text({
                    font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                    }),
                    backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
                      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
                    }),
                    padding: [2, 2, 2, 2],
                    textBaseline: 'bottom',
                    offsetY: -12,
                  }),
                  image: new ol.style.Icon({
                    src: new ol.style.RegularShape({
                      radius: 6,
                      points: 3,
                      angle: Math.PI,
                      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
                      }),
                    }).getImage(1).toDataURL(),
                    anchor: [0.5, 1],
                  }),
                })
              );
            }
            const segmentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(segment.getCoordinateAt(0.5));
            segmentStyles[count].setGeometry(segmentPoint);
            segmentStyles[count].getText().setText(label);
            styles.push(segmentStyles[count]);
            count++;
          });
        }
        if (label) {
          labelStyle.setGeometry(point);
          labelStyle.getText().setText(label);
          styles.push(labelStyle);
        }
        if (
          tip &&
          type === 'Point' &&
          !modifying
        ) {
          tipPoint = geometry;
          tipStyle.getText().setText(tip);
          styles.push(tipStyle);
        }
        modifying = false;
        return styles;
      }

      const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: function (feature) {
          return styleFunction(feature, showSegments.checked);
        },
      });

      const map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-11000000, 4600000],
          zoom: 15,
        }),
      });

      map.addInteraction(modify);

      let draw; // global so we can remove it later

      function addInteraction() {
        map.removeInteraction(draw);
        const drawType = typeSelect.value;
        if (typeSelectForm.style.display == 'none') {
          modify.setActive(false);
          return;
        }
        const activeTip =
          'Click to continue drawing the ' +
          (drawType === 'Polygon' ? 'polygon' : 'line');
        const idleTip = 'Click to start measuring';
        let tip = idleTip;
        draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
          source: source,
          type: drawType,
          style: function (feature) {
            return styleFunction(feature, showSegments.checked, drawType, tip);
          },
        });
        draw.on('drawstart', function () {
          if (clearPrevious.checked) {
            source.clear();
          }
          modify.setActive(false);
          tip = activeTip;
        });
        draw.on('drawend', function () {
          modifyStyle.setGeometry(tipPoint);
          modify.setActive(true);
          map.once('pointermove', function () {
            modifyStyle.setGeometry();
          });
          tip = idleTip;
        });
        modify.setActive(true);
        map.addInteraction(draw);
      }

      typeSelect.onchange = function () {
        addInteraction();
      };

      addInteraction();

      showSegments.onchange = function () {
        vector.changed();
      };


var measuring = false;
var measureControl = (function (Control) {
    measureControl = function(opt_options) {

      var options = opt_options || {};

      var button = document.createElement('button');
      button.className += ' fas fa-ruler ';

      var this_ = this;
      var handleMeasure = function(e) {
        if (!measuring) {
            typeSelectForm.style.display = '';
            addInteraction();
            measuring = true;
        } else {
            typeSelectForm.style.display = 'none';
            addInteraction();
            measuring = false;
        }
      };

      button.addEventListener('click', handleMeasure, false);
      button.addEventListener('touchstart', handleMeasure, false);

      var element = document.createElement('div');
      element.className = 'measure-control ol-unselectable ol-control';
      element.appendChild(button);

      ol.control.Control.call(this, {
        element: element,
        target: options.target
      });

    };
    if (Control) measureControl.__proto__ = Control;
    measureControl.prototype = Object.create(Control && Control.prototype);
    measureControl.prototype.constructor = measureControl;
    return measureControl;
}(ol.control.Control));


      map.addControl(new measureControl());

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems the qgis2web code uses the variable `sketch` to determine if its own measure is active (the `onSingleClick` function does nothing if it is), so instead of using a new variable you could use that

```
sketch = false;
var measureControl = (function (Control) {
    measureControl = function(opt_options) {

      var options = opt_options || {};

      var button = document.createElement('button');
      button.className += ' fas fa-ruler ';

      var this_ = this;
      var handleMeasure = function(e) {
        if (!sketch) {
            typeSelectForm.style.display = '';
            addInteraction();
            sketch = true;
        } else {
            typeSelectForm.style.display = 'none';
            addInteraction();
            sketch = false;
        }
      };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the code that you propose to me activates by default the mouse arrow in measurement mode, while the extraction coming from qgis2web has as default the click to query the features. how can I integrate your code by activating it by clicking on an icon like the link in my first question?

Comment: I've added a None option so you can switch on and off as well as between geometry types

Comment: Ok, only now I understand the None option. Thank you. Now I can have all the form visible on the map with the various options but if I select length or area the command is not activated. Can you help me to deactivate qgis2web's current default measureControl and activate the one you propose?

Comment: I presume you would set Measure Tool to None in the menu https://qgis2web-docstests.readthedocs.io/en/testing/

Comment: to simplify I modified my initial question by inserting the index.html and the qgis2web.js, I can't get the code of the latter to work together with the code you proposed. I only work alternately.

Comment: You will need to add the `<form>` block in my updated example to your html, plus the css for the form and measure-control and `position: relative` the map for the form to work correctly.  Then add all the javascript, but since you already have a map replace the `new ol.Map` block with `map.addLayer(vector);`

Comment: The qgis2web code does not know your measure is active, but it has an unused variable which you could use to indicate that as in my update.

Comment: I took a copy of your code.  onSingleClick is a problem, but even with the onSingleClick and pointermove handlers removed, when the measure is active clicking the map causes some of the labels to disappear, and the interaction to stop.  I cannot see the reason for that yet.

Comment: I try another way. look at this code https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html , it is the exact same as the one in qgis2web (even the comments), however the area measurement has been removed. The output is uglier than yours but maybe with your experience you can reintagrate the area measurement?

Comment: Sorry, this code i want to link https://tsauerwein.github.io/ol3/animation-flights/examples/measure.html

Comment: That is what the qgis2web measure is based on.  It does not allow modify.